# Facing issues adding destination while creating a dynamic contact form for S3 static website using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I have been trying to create a email form for my website using AWS Lambda, *Amazon API Gateway* and SES.

I followed the instructions provided in the [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/create-dynamic-contact-forms-for-s3-static-websites-using-aws-lambda-amazon-api-gateway-and-amazon-ses/) by AWS. The instructions for adding destinations and creating a link between the mailFwd and the destinations are not provided by the article.

Also, there is a part of the article which mentions adding a code snippet under the policy so that SES can access the lambda function. I can't find where the policy section is.

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application flow looks like this:

```
JavaScript / HTML -> API Gateway -> AWS Lambda Function mailfwd -> SES
```

This means, your frontend sends an HTTP request to the API Gateway which forwards an HTTP event to your Lambda function and your Lambda function processes the mail data from the HTTP event and forwards it to SES.

To avoid any confusion: SES is neither calling nor accessing your Lambda function, it's only the other way around. In order to allow the Lambda function to call SES and send a mail, you have to copy the IAM policy from the blog post (the policy about `ses:SendMail`) to the policy of your Lambda function's IAM role. (I admit that the blog post's wording is a bit confusing here).

Besides that, you don't need to create any links between the services. You only need to tell API Gateway which Lambda function to call if an HTTP request comes in. In this case you choose the `mailfwd` function as mentioned in the article:

> 3. Select your newly-created resource and choose “create method.”  Choose a POST.  Here, you will choose our AWS Lambda Function. To do this, select “**mailfwd**” from the drop down.

Comment: Thank you! @s.hesse

Comment: I worked on it as per your instructions, and it worked. The testing process for the lambda function was a success. However, after pasting the URL of the API Gateway to the script section of the page, the website still doesn't process the request.

Comment: Do you get any error when sending the request? Or does it work if you manually access the API Gateway endpoint using a tool like Postman or curl ?

Comment: yes, I get an error if I try to send a request from the webpage. Am I missing out on something? Do I have to add a destination for my lambda function? @s.hesse

Comment: And what error do you get? :-) Provide as much details as possible, so it's easier to help :-)

Comment: Hi, sorry for a delayed response. My Lambda function works and sends email while testing, but there seems to be some issue with the SES and the HTML code where I have attached the script with the link to the API Gateway. whenever I try to fill the form on the website and click on submit, the website prompts a message "unsuccessful", that means it does not send any email to the mail server. In a nutshell, the lambda function is fine, there seems to be an issue with API Gateway.